# What's the convention for extending Linq datacontext with set based helper operations specific to one collection of entities only

Tags: linq, helper, extend, partial-classes

I might be vaguing out here but I'm looking for a nice place to put set based helper operations in linq so I can do things like;

```
db.Selections.ClearTemporary()
```

which does something like

```
db.DeleteAllOnSubmit(db.Selections.Where(s => s.Temporary))
```

Since I can figure out how to extend `Table<Selection>` the best I can do is create a static method in partial class of Selection (similar to Ruby)  but I have to pass in the datacontext like;

```
Selection.ClearTemporary(MyDataContext)
```

This kind of sucks because I have two conventions for doing set based operations and I have to pass the data context to the static class.

I've seen other people recommending piling helper methods into a partial of the datacontext like;

```
myDataContext.ClearTemporarySelections();
```

But I feel this makes the dc a dumping ground for in-cohesive operations.

Surely I'm missing something.  I hope so.  What's the convention?

Answer (score 2):

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
  public static void Clear<T>(this Table<T> t, Expression<Func<T,bool>> pred)
  {
    t.DeleteAllOnSubmit(t.Where(pred));
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
db.Selections.Clear(x => x.Temporary);
```

If needed, the `DataContext` can be accessed from a `Table<T>`.

Comment: Gives me something else to work with but applies to all entities.  Since .Selections is actually getter for a generic type Table<T> and not a class I suppose extending these are a dead end.    Sorry to reply so late I never received notification by email of this.

Comment: Adding `SubmitChanges` is a terrible idea here (extremely unintuitive with unpredictable side effects). I'll turn my -1 to a +1 without it.

Comment: I just realized you answered by question title perfectly - great answer stupid question.  I've edited my question title but what's the protocol?

Comment: Yeah I was sketchy about the submit changes as it could unleash all sorts of mayhem on the unsuspecting user.  However I was pretty pleased to discover Table<T> has a context reference to the parent context - I'd been looking for that in other scenarios.

Comment: @280Z28: I know it is terrible  :)  It was an example of how to get to the DataContext from a Table so only one parameter needs to be passed.

Comment: But you don't need the data context if you aren't submitting it.

Comment: @280Z28: Ok, I'll remove it...  but Luke did say he had the 'burden' of passing the datacontext. I am simply showing you do not need a datacontext when you have the table already  :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking of creating nested classes as partials of the datacontext plus a getter that initializes and returns the nested class

```
public SelectionsHelperClass SelectionsHelper {
  get {
    return new SelectionsHelperClass(Selections)
  }
}
```

This way I can do `db.SelectionsHelper.ClearTemporary()` without passing in the context while keeping set based operations (collection operations) specific to Selections logically together.  I haven't tested this.

Something I forgot to mentioned is that reason I want these helpers is that they are frequently shared by some but not all controllers in an asp mvc app and I'm looking for a place to refactor them too.

Comment: I've tested this and it works ok.  My first usage was for a lookup table - So now I can do things like db.LookupsHelper.GetDropDownValues("User.Type"); instead of - from l in db.lookups where attribute == "User.Type" select new {l.lookupid, l.displaytext}